# azure information protection remove label in linux

Tags: python, linux, azure

I am in a situation that requires (decrypting/removeLabel) in Linux eg. Debian or rasbian ?
I have looked into azure products and they clearly stated that there is no "official" support for Linux..... but my question here is .... is there any workaround to achieve this in Linux?

One silly way I could think of is to get this protected file in a windows pc, decrypt it and send it to the Linux PC over scp.... but this requires me to have a sort of a bypass PC to run just for this ...seems pretty silly ... any ideas/suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Azure Information Protection dont have an official client for linux, one solution would be to use a windows virtual machine on your linux system and install the `AIP` client in it, `VirtualBox` or `Vmware` are good choices here. You can also use the `AIP` PowerShell module to automate the removal of labels